# jQuery.get() fails when url is in the parent directory of the origin url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have a web page that needs to check the contents of a file that resides on the same partition as the origin URL.

My origin URL is: `file:///C:/work/run/report/index.html`

This URL has a frame that shows another URL: `file:///C:/work/run/report/dir1/dir2/frame.html`

This frame tries to send a get request to `file:///C:/work/run/log/log.html` (using relative path: `"../../../" + log/log.html`) using the following excerpt:

```
$.get("../../../" + log/log.html, function( data ) {
    checkIfLogFileContentsIncludeBookmark(data);
},"html");
```

This fails.

However, when trying to perform the same get to a URL that resides inside the origin URL's directory: `file:///C:/work/run/report/log/log.html` (using relative path: `"../../" + log/log.html`), it works fine, using the same code:

```
$.get("../../" + log/log.html, function( data ) {
    checkIfLogFileContentsIncludeBookmark(data);
},"html");
```

Is there some known limitation of `jQuery.get()`, JavaScript in general or URLs in general I'm missing?

Comment: You should not be using local file URLs for serving HTML :) Run it on a local server. Ajax will not allow local file requests outside of the scope of the original source file.

Comment: Can you suggest a local server that can run on windows and unix?

Comment: [`python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530787/simple-http-web-server)

Comment: The problem is the fact that my program is a stand-alone one, and it runs on many clients (I can not run HTTP server on each of them). Is there another option without using ajax? We need a solution for client side.

Comment: To avoid using a server completely, you will have to have only links and no Ajax. That other option is to wrap a browser control in a Windows Forms app to get some control over loading back, but that is probably more work. You so mention unix as well, so a WinfForms app is probably not a good solution